# Isomorphism between the conformal group and SO

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

In CFT, one constructs the generators of various confromal transformations, and re-expresses them in terms of $J_{ab}$'s that manifestly satisfy commutation relations of $so(d+1,1)$ (taking Euclidean spacetime). Then it is claimed, everywhere I looked and in particular in Di Francesco et al page 98, that this forms an isomorphism between the conformal group in $d$ dimensions and $SO(d+1,1)$.

My question is: why $SO(d+1,1)$ and not $O(d+1,1)$?

Comment: Dilatations are part of the $SO(d+1, 1)$ algebra. They have det $=1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, was sloppy. Edited. Still, how can one see that it is SO and not O?

Comment: The exponential mapping links the generators of a Lie algebra to the conncted component of identity of a Lie group.

Comment: ((cosθ, sinθ),(sinθ,-cosθ))  is orthogonal and so in O(2); but not in SO(2). You *really* don't want to take its logarithm.

Comment: Ok, is there anything else you are willing to share? No, I did not get it. What's the point in counting the generators if SO(p,q) is disconnected? Of course the group dimension is larger than the generators, but how is that useful information in this case? Also, and maybe I misunderstand here, but O and SO share the same algebra

Comment: Well, yes and no. Review the [topology of O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group).  *One* connected component of it is the subgroup SO(2) with generator $i\sigma_2$, but the other does not include the identity, so it has no generators to "share" with SO(2): take θ=0 in the n=2 example in my comment.   It has detG= -1, so it lacks the identity. So you always discuss the same algebra of the same group and subgroup.

Comment: ... but [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Conformal_group) goes further than the Lie algebra of SO(n) as a subgroup of O(n) and, geometrically, links the conformal group to O(n). The takeaway is that  contrasting O(n) to its subgroup SO(n) goes beyond the Lie algebra.